# Context menu not working on form only on objects

Tags: c#, winforms, contextmenu

I all of a sudden can get my ContextMenuStrip to work on the form window itself. If i right click on my label or on my notify icon it works but nothing happens on the form itself. I'm certain it worked before I renamed the form but I can't seem to find out where the problem could stem from.
The ContextMenuStrip is correctly and identically set on both the form as well as the label and notify icon.

Anybody know where there problem could be? If my code is needed I will add it.

Comment: What code do you need? The *.Designer.cs code or the Form code?

Answer (score 0):

Check forms **ContextMenuStrip** property is properly set.

Comment: On object **ContextMenuStrip** property is set and on form this property might not be set.

Check on property window.

Comment: As I stated in the original question, the ContextMenuStrip property is set in both the form and the objects. And they are set up identically.